# Ubuntu linux installation without internet connection

Tags: linux, installer, packages

how can we install the packages from the CD of the Ubuntu if net is not available?

Comment: It's an operating system installation/administration question, not a programming question; and the experts for that are next door, at Superuser.com.

Comment: lol, I'm going to call it UBANTU from now on

Answer (score 3):

The CD is specifically designed to permit installation without the Internet. You boot from it, it asks a bunch of questions, then it installs itself to your machine.

You may be missing the latest updates, but you will have a good complete working system by the time it's through.

If you don't already have such a CD, you can have one shipped to you by mail from this order page: https://shipit.ubuntu.com/ . The Ubuntu folks are so nice they'll do that, for free!

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure the CD is:

- In the drive
- Enabled (checked) in your Software Sources, under the System menu (at the bottom of the Ubuntu Software tab)

If it's checked in sources and present in the drive, you should be able to install (using synaptic or whatever) packages from it.

Answer (score 1):

The install CD can be added as [repository](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#CD-ROM/DVD). See [RepositoriesUbuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu) for more details.

Another option is to use `apt-cdrom`. See [AptCdrom](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptCdrom) for more details.

At the end, you'll just end up with another entry in `/etc/apt/sources.list` looking like this:

```
deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 9.10 _Karmic_Koala - Release i386 (20081029.1)]/ karmic main restricted
```

Answer (score 0):

Have the `.deb` packages on a CD and go from there?

You don't need a network connection (certainly not to the Internet) to install packages stored on a CD.

Answer (score 0):

You can have used saved downloads done earlier on your system or on others system. Ubuntu downloads all packages and stores at a place in your system before installing them.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
 dpkg -i /path/to/package.deb
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dpkg